# To change parent variable from child component using @Output

Tags: angular

**What i want** - When i click on feedback button, a feedback form with cancel & submit button should open. Once i click cancel/submit, feedback form should get closed. if i click on feedback button again, **feedback form should open again.**

**What's happening** - When i click on feedback button, a feedback form with cancel & submit button is coming. Once i click on cancel/submit, feedback form getting closed.  but if i click on feedback button again, **feedback form NOT opening.**

**What i have done** - 
I have a button on parent component & on click calling feedback component (by default feedback page will be hidden) like this -

**app.component.html**

```
<button type="button" (click)="showFeedbackForm()">Feedback</button>

<div *ngIf="feedbackForm">
    <app-feedback (onHide)="changeHide($event)"></app-feedback>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  feedbackForm = false;

  showFeedbackForm() {
    this.feedbackForm = true;
  }

  changeHide(val: boolean) {
    this.feedbackForm = val;
    console.log("changeHide :: ", this.feedbackForm); // this feedbackForm value is not getting updated.
  }

}
```

& feedback component looks like this -

**feedback.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="feedback"> 
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="cancel" value="cancel" (click)="closeFeedback()">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**feedback.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-feedback",
  templateUrl: "./feedback.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./feedback.component.css"]
})
export class FeedbackComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  feedback = true;
  closeFeedback() {
    this.feedback = false;
    this.setHide();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("onSubmit called");
  }

  @Output() feedbackForm = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  setHide() {
    this.feedbackForm.emit(false);
  }

}
```

Here on click of feedback button 2nd time, feedback component is not getting called.

I am not sure if i am doing it right way. stackblitz link is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gue67m). Please Feel free to update.

**Please help / guide me**

Comment: Try renaming your ouput property as : `@Output() onHide = ...`. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztjklx?file=src/app/feedback/feedback.component.ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many redundant and structured in a wrong way code for such an easy task. I played around a little with the provided code. The solution may look like so (some naming must be fixed, but I've left it as it was):

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  isVisible = false;

  showFeedbackForm() {
    this.isVisible = true;
  }

  changeHide() {
    this.isVisible = false;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<button type="button" (click)="showFeedbackForm()">Feedback</button>

<div>
    <app-feedback (close)="changeHide()" *ngIf="isVisible"></app-feedback>
</div>
```

feedback.component.ts

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-feedback",
  templateUrl: "./feedback.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./feedback.component.css"]
})
export class FeedbackComponent {
  @Output() close = new EventEmitter<void>();

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("onSubmit called");
  }

  closeFeedback() {
    this.close.emit();
  }
}
```

feedback.component.html

```
<p>
    feedback works!
</p>
<div> 
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="cancel" value="cancel" (click)="closeFeedback()">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in app.component.html

`<app-feedback (feedbackForm)="changeHide($event)"></app-feedback>`

only issue is that in feedback.component.ts out property is 
`this.feedbackForm.emit(false);` while you are using (onHide).

You should use `feedbackForm` as output property as given above.

you just need to change this line.
`<app-feedback (feedbackForm)="changeHide($event)"></app-feedback>`

Let me know if you have any doubt.